# SQL Recursion to eliminate duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table from which I want to select values, but only if there is exactly one entry in the column "id_new". After I have selected those ids, I would update these ids and mark them as "ready" in the source table. Those ids (id_orig) would be ignored if the select would run again. The problem is, that there could be many steps needed to find all entries, which have exactly one entry for "id_new".

sample data:

| id_orig | id_new |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 10 | 5 |
| 10 | 20 |
| 11 | 20 |
| 11 | 40 |
| 500 | 40 |

For the sample data it would mean:
1.) select all columns where there is only one entry for id_new.
2.) redo the same sql but ignore the columns where id_orig was already selected. This would result in finding (11, 20). I could repeat this and would find (500, 40) in the third step.
[image]
I also wrote a long sql to find the same rows, but I am wondering if you can achieve the same result in a simpler way, maybe recursive?

```
select * from mytable where id_new in (select id_new from mytable group by id_new having count(*) = 1)
union
select a.* from mytable  a
where a.id_new in (select id_new from mytable where id_orig in 
(select id_orig from mytable where id_new in 
(select id_new from mytable group by id_new having count(*) = 1)))
and a.id_orig not in (
select id_orig from mytable where id_new in (select id_new from mytable group by id_new having count(*) = 1))
union all
select a.* from mytable  a
 where a.id_new in ( select id_new from mytable where id_orig in (select id_orig from mytable where id_new in (
select a.id_new from mytable  a
 where a.id_new in (select id_new from mytable where id_orig in 
(select id_orig from mytable where id_new in 
(select id_new from mytable group by id_new having count(*) = 1)))
and a.id_orig not in (
select id_orig from mytable where id_new in (select id_new from mytable group by id_new having count(*) = 1))
)))
and a.id_orig not in (
select id_orig from mytable where id_new in (select id_new from mytable group by id_new having count(*) = 1)
union all
select a.id_orig from mytable  a
 where a.id_new in (select id_new from mytable where id_orig in 
(select id_orig from mytable where id_new in 
(select id_new from mytable group by id_new having count(*) = 1)))
and a.id_orig not in (
select id_orig from mytable where id_new in (select id_new from mytable group by id_new having count(*) = 1))
)
```

Comment: You have tagged your question with both [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server]. The latter indicates Microsoft SQL Server, which is a different product from MySQL. Can you please clarify which brand you are using? What does `SELECT @@version;` return? (that command should work in both brands.)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, that was a mistake. I am using mysql.

Comment: On the second run you would still find `10  20` and `11  20` which is the same `id_new` so how is your logic working to now include these?

Comment: can you share more sample rows with corner-cases from the source table?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a window function would help eg ROW_NUMBER() (see [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html)).

```
  select id_orig, id_new
  , row_number() over ( partition by id_orig order by id_new ) rn_
  from t ;

  -- result
  id_orig   id_new  rn_
   1        2       1
   3        4       1
   10       5       1
   10       20      2   -- 2 rows for this id!
   11       20      1
   11       40      2   -- 2 rows for this id!
   500      40      1
```

Once you have this result, you can eliminate all the extraneous rows by using the initial query as a subquery, and adding a WHERE clause:

```
select *
from (
  select id_orig, id_new
  , row_number() over ( partition by id_orig order by id_new ) rn_
  from t
) sq
where rn_ = 1 ; 

--result
id_orig id_new  rn_
1       2       1
3       4       1
10      5       1
11      20      1
500     40      1
```

(If you don't want the rn_ column in the output, just write SELECT id_orig, id_ new ... in the outer query.)

[DBfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bbf5cefa2f94def6fdc7f5a1a11d9399).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately this is not solving my problem. If I had two entries with the same "id_new" but different "id_orig", I would not want to select any of those entries. (e.g. (600, 700) (601,700)). I already tried different kind of window functions, but they didn't get me the desired result.

Comment: @moons Not quite sure why you would eliminate (600,700) and (601,700) completely.  In your question, there is id_new 20 with 2 rows, with the first instance labelled _ignore_ and the second instance with a green tick.  Would you remove these 2 rows (id_new 20) from the result set, too?  And what about the 2 rows with new_id 40 (also labelled with _ignore_ and a green tick, respectively).

Comment: @moons  Is this closer to the required result?  
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fd12b62bbcf3436300cff2589f6d1a9c

Comment: This is because of the corresponding id_orig. Because I already found an entry for the id_orig "10" (first sql), I want to ignore all rows with id_orig= 10 in the next step(s). The same goes for id_new = 40.

Answer (score 0):

You can UNION, all single number with all Dup0licates, that have the higher id_orig.

> ```
>   select MIN(t.id_orig) as id_orig, t.id_new
>   from t 
>   GROUP BY t.id_new
>   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
>   UNION
>   select t.id_orig, t.id_new
>   from t INNER JOIN t as t1 ON t.id_new = t1.id_new AND t.id_orig > t1.id_orig;
> ```
>
> ```
> id_orig | id_new
> ------: | -----:
>       1 |      2
>       3 |      4
>      10 |      5
>      11 |     20
>     500 |     40
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c1c18d30c429427f128ee3d2d07c492e)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I can't guarantee, that the "correct" id_orig will always be higher. Additionally if there were two rows for the same id_new (e.g. (600, 700) (601,700)) this entry should not be selected, because there is no clarity which entry is the "correct" one.

Comment: *nor clear* is not possible in any laguage, you need an algorithm that determines, which entry will be taken. An alghorithm as inteligenzt as it might be, can't guess. You can make it more an more complicated as you add more and more rules, but that would be not in the scope of the site. what you need to do, is take my code and extend for every occasion the `ON` or even better don't have duplicates inb the first place for the new ids

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not expressing myself clearly enough.. :( There are clear rules, which entries should be taken and the algorithm shall not guess. Therefore I thought that there was a simple SQL solution for this task, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case. So I either need to run multiple updates sequentially or write a stored procedure, that does the job. Thanks anyway.

Comment: i don't understand the rules or you presented data didn't show all possibiliteies, but you can adept my answer easily with case WHEn to fit you needs.